# Listbox value pass in store in to variable using for loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, listbox

I have 100 order number in `listbox` and that number is part or file name. what i need to do is search file name using order number from list box. Example value is list box is

- 456789-789464
- 879746-123456

and file name is 456789-789464-2013-11-23456-456.pdf.

Logic for finding file is working but i cannot pass all order number from list box in to variable. I m using below code

```
   MOOOR as string = ""

   For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items(1)
       MOOOR &= item & vbCrLf
   Next
```

With this for loop i m getting msg ("Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'")

Comment: I suppose that this is required in VB.NET. If so add the appropriate TAG to have a wider visibility for your question

Comment: How do you fill the Listbox? Do you use a DataTable/DataView ?

Comment: What type of project:  WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Your ListBox1 is probably bound to a DataTable( or DataView) and so the Items are DataRowView so the ListBox1.Items(1).Row is the Row(1) of your table.

To find selected items you need something like ([WD: How to Determine Which Items Are Selected in a ListBox](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/201669)):

```
For x = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
   If ListBox1.Selected(x) = True Then
             msg = msg &amp; ListBox1.List(x) &amp; vbCrLf
   End If
Next x
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. List box is bound to datatable. I find solution and its working now. Thanks once gain to all

Comment: If this answer is answer to your question please accept it. If the solution is different it can be useful to put it as answer or write it to your question to enable other people to use knowledge.